# Can't connect externally to Neo4j server in AKS cluster using Neo4j browser

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ssl, neo4j

I have an `AKS` cluster with a `Node.js` server connecting to a `Neo4j-standalone` instance all deployed with `Helm`.
I installed an `ingress-nginx` controller, referenced a default `Let's Encrypt` certificate and habilitated TPC ports with Terraform as

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx" {
  name      = "ingress-nginx"
  repository = "ingress-nginx"
  # repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart     = "ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx"
  namespace = "default"


  set {
    name = "tcp.7687"
    value = "default/cluster:7687"
  }
  set {
    name = "tcp.7474"
    value = "default/cluster:7474"
  }
  set {
    name = "tcp.7473"
    value = "default/cluster:7473"
  }
  set {
    name = "tcp.6362"
    value = "default/cluster-admin:6362"
  }
  set {
    name = "tcp.7687"
    value = "default/cluster-admin:7687"
  }
  set {
    name = "tcp.7474"
    value = "default/cluster-admin:7474"
  }
  set {
    name = "tcp.7473"
    value = "default/cluster-admin:7473"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.extraArgs.default-ssl-certificate"
    value = "default/tls-secret"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
    value = "Local"
  }
  set {
    name = "controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"
    value = "true"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = var.public_ip_address
  }
  set {
    name = "controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-dns-label-name"
    value = "xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"
    value = "/healthz"
  }
}
```

I then have an Ingress with paths pointing to `Neo4j` services so on `https://xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/neo4j-tcp-http/browser/` I can get to the browser.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2$3$4
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    # certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: http01
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-issuer
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts: 
    - xxxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: tls-secret 
  rules:
    # - host: xxx.westeurope.cloud.app.azure.com #dns from Azure PublicIP


### Node.js server
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: server-clusterip-service
            port:
              number: 80 

  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /server(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: server-clusterip-service
            port:
              number: 80

##### Neo4j

  - http:
      paths:            
        # 502 bad gateway
        # /any character 502 bad gatway
        - path: /neo4j-tcp-bolt(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              # neo4j chart
              # name: cluster

              # neo4j-standalone chart
              name: neo4j
              port: 
                # name: tcp-bolt
                number: 7687
  - http:
      paths:   
        # /browser/ show browser
        #/any character shows login to xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:443 from https, :80 from http
        - path: /neo4j-tcp-http(/|$)(.*) 
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              # neo4j chart
              # name: cluster

              # neo4j-standalone chart
              name: neo4j
              port: 
                # name: tcp-http
                number: 7474
  - http:
      paths:            
        - path: /neo4j-tcp-https(/|$)(.*) 
        # 502 bad gateway
        # /any character 502 bad gatway
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              # neo4j chart
              # name: cluster

              # neo4j-standalone chart
              name: neo4j
              port: 
                # name: tcp-https
                number: 7473
```

I can get to the Neo4j Browser on the `https://xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/neo4j-tcp-http/browser/` but using the Connect Url `bolt+s//server.bolt` it won't connect to the server with the error `ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver..`
Now I'm guessing that is because Neo4j bolt connector is not using the Certificate used by the `ingress-nginx`controller.

```
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air helm_charts % kubectl describe secret tls-secret
Name:         tls-secret
Namespace:    default
Labels:       controller.cert-manager.io/fao=true
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/alt-names: xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
              cert-manager.io/certificate-name: tls-certificate
              cert-manager.io/common-name: xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
              cert-manager.io/ip-sans: 
              cert-manager.io/issuer-group: 
              cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: ClusterIssuer
              cert-manager.io/issuer-name: letsencrypt-issuer
              cert-manager.io/uri-sans: 

Type:  kubernetes.io/tls

Data
====
tls.crt:  5648 bytes
tls.key:  1679 bytes
```

I tried to use it overriding the chart values, but then the Neo4j driver from Node.js server won't connect to the server ..

```
  ssl:
  # setting per "connector" matching neo4j config
    bolt:
      privateKey:
        secretName: tls-secret # we set up the template to grab `private.key` from this secret
        subPath:  tls.key # we specify the privateKey value name to get from the secret
      publicCertificate:
        secretName: tls-secret # we set up the template to grab `public.crt` from this secret
        subPath:  tls.crt # we specify the publicCertificate value name to get from the secret
      trustedCerts:
        sources: [ ] # a sources array for a projected volume - this allows someone to (relatively) easily mount multiple public certs from multiple secrets for example.
      revokedCerts:
        sources: [ ]  # a sources array for a projected volume
    https:
      privateKey:
        secretName: tls-secret
        subPath: tls.key
      publicCertificate:
        secretName: tls-secret
        subPath: tls.crt
      trustedCerts:
        sources: [ ]
      revokedCerts:
        sources: [ ]
```

Is there a way to use it or should I setup another certificate just for Neo4j? If so what would it be the dnsNames to set on it?

Is there something else I'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a few days of going in circles I found what the problems were..

First using a `Staging` certificate will cause Neo4j bolt connection to fail, as it's not `Trusted`, with error:

> ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3

found here https://grishagin.com/neo4j/2022/03/29/neo4j-websocket-issue.html

Then I was missing to assign a general listening address to the bolt connector as it's listening by default only to `127.0.0.0:7687` https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/

> To listen for Bolt connections on all network interfaces (0.0.0.0)

so I added `server.bolt.listen_address: "0.0.0.0:7687"` to Neo4j chart values `config`.

Next, as I'm connecting the default `neo4j` `ClusterIP` service tcp ports to the ingress controller's `exposed TCP connections` through the `Ingress` as described here https://neo4j.com/labs/neo4j-helm/1.0.0/externalexposure/ as an alternative to using a `LoadBalancer`, the Neo4j `LoadBalancer` services is not needed so the `services:neo4j:enabled` gets set to "false", in my tests I actually found that if you leave it enabled bolt won't connect despite setting everything correctly..

Other Neo4j missing `config` where `server.bolt.enabled : "true"`, `server.bolt.tls_level: "REQUIRED"`, `dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.client_auth: "NONE"` and `dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.enabled: "true"` the complete list of config options is here https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/

Neo4j chart's values for `ssl` config were fine.

So now I can use the (renamed for brevity) path `/neo4j/browser/` to serve the `Neo4j Browser` app, and either the `/bolt` path as the browser `Connect URL`, or PublicIP's `<DSN>:<bolt port>`.

> You are connected as user neo4j
> to bolt+s://xxxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/bolt
> Connection credentials are stored in your web browser.

Hope this explanation and the code recap below will help others.

Cheers.

## ingress controller

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx" {
  name      = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace = "default"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx" 
  chart = "ingress-nginx"
  set {
    name  = "version"
    value = "4.4.2"

  }
### expose tcp connections for neo4j service
  ### bolt url connection port
  set {
    name = "tcp.7687"
    value = "default/neo4j:7687"
  }
  ### http browser app port
  set {
    name = "tcp.7474"
    value = "default/neo4j:7474"
  }


  set {
    name  = "controller.extraArgs.default-ssl-certificate"
    value = "default/tls-secret"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
    value = "Local"
  }
  set {
    name = "controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"
    value = "true"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = var.public_ip_address
  }
  set {
    name = "controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-dns-label-name"
    value = "xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"
    value = "/healthz"
  }
}
```

## Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2$3$4
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-issuer

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts: 
    - xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: tls-secret 
  rules:


### Node.js server
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: server-clusterip-service
            port:
              number: 80 
            

  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /server(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: server-clusterip-service
            port:
              number: 80

##### Neo4j

  - http:
      paths:            
        - path: /bolt(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: neo4j
              port: 
                # name: tcp-bolt
                number: 7687
  - http:
      paths:   
        - path: /neo4j(/|$)(.*) 
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: neo4j
              port: 
                # name: tcp-http
                number: 7474
```

## Values.yaml (Umbrella chart)

```
neo4j-db: #chart dependency alias
  nameOverride: "neo4j"
  fullnameOverride: 'neo4j'
  neo4j:
   # Name of your cluster
    name: "xxxx" # this will be the label: app: value for the service selector
    password: "xxxxx"
    ##
    passwordFromSecret: ""
    passwordFromSecretLookup: false
    edition: "community"
    acceptLicenseAgreement: "yes"
    offlineMaintenanceModeEnabled: false 
    resources:
      cpu: "1000m"
      memory: "2Gi"

  volumes:
    data:

      mode: 'volumeClaimTemplate'
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: neo4j-sc-data
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 4Gi


    backups:
      mode: 'share' # share an existing volume (e.g. the data volume)
      share:
        name: 'logs'

    logs:
      mode: 'volumeClaimTemplate'
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: neo4j-sc-logs
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 4Gi


  services:
  # A LoadBalancer Service for external Neo4j driver applications and Neo4j Browser, this will create "cluster-neo4j" svc
    neo4j:
      enabled: false 
  
  config:
     
    server.bolt.enabled : "true"
    server.bolt.tls_level: "REQUIRED"
    server.bolt.listen_address: "0.0.0.0:7687"
    dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.client_auth: "NONE"
    dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.enabled: "true"
    

  
  startupProbe:
    failureThreshold: 1000
    periodSeconds: 50

  ssl:
    bolt:
      privateKey:
        secretName: tls-secret 
        subPath:  tls.key 
      publicCertificate:
        secretName: tls-secret 
        subPath:  tls.crt 
      trustedCerts:
        sources: [ ] 
      revokedCerts:
        sources: [ ]  # a sources array for a projected volume
```

Comment: Can you please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/q/77689238/17778275

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your information, the problem seems to be that you're trying to expose the bolt port behind an ingress. Ingresses are implemented as an L7 (protocol aware) reverse proxy and manage load-balancing etc. The bolt protocol has its load balancing and routing for cluster applications. So you will need to expose the network service directly for every instance of neo4j you are running.

Check out this part of the documentation for more information:
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/kubernetes/accessing-neo4j/#access-outside-k8s

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for answering, I'm going in circles. I'm actually trying to do what's described here https://neo4j.com/labs/neo4j-helm/1.0.0/externalexposure/ ("There are other options, such as the nginx-ingress controller which can be configured to support TCP connections but in this guide we’re shooting for something as simple as possible that you can do with standard Kubernetes resource types.") by configuring the ingress controller I'm using (ingress-nginx, not nginx-ingress) to expose tcp connections to the ClusterIp services created by the helm chart, not the LoasBalancer.

Comment: The link you suggested confused me a bit more if possible lol.. Applications accessing Neo4j from outside Kubernetes Enterprise Edition only ??

Comment: Oh, for sure. Welcome to SO. It's a great community :)

Comment: Thank you @Vincenzo. Been a passive consumer for years. But it's time to contribute a bit.  I think the reason it's flagged as Enterprise edition is that the backup port is included, and online backups are only available in enterprise edition. rest should be the same

Comment: Oh I see, In fact I could make it work for connecting to the browser from a route in my ingress, and thought it might just indicate that some related functionalities were capped for the community edition.