# Unable to access specific neo4j database exposed using AKS

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, neo4j, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have an aks cluster with two neo4j database images (db-1 and db-2) in it, services for those. Using nginx ingress controller, I want to route the user to a particular database based on the url he requests for example if user wants to go to db-1, my neo4j url will be `http://<external-ip>/db1`

I want to use an internal IP, and have my aks cluster linked to it.

I have used the following steps to create the databases, and nginx controller. Yet my databases are not being connected. Neo4j says `Service Unavailable`

`helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx`

`helm repo update`

`helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --create-namespace  --namespace ingress-test  --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz  --set-string controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"="true" --tcp-services-configmap=ingress-test/tcp-services`

Applying the below yaml `kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml`

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aks-neo4j-one  
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aks-neo4j-one
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aks-neo4j-one
    spec:
      containers:  
      - name: neo4j  
        image: neo4j:latest 
        env:      
           - name: NEO4J_AUTH       
             value: neo4j/<mypassword>      
        ports:  
        - containerPort: 7474  
          name: http
        - containerPort: 7687  
          name: tcp
        
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aks-neo4j-one  
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:  
    - protocol: TCP  
      port: 80  
      targetPort: 7687 
  selector:
    app: aks-neo4j-one
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: neo4j-ingress  
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /neo4jone
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aks-neo4j-one
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-test
data:
  7687: "ingress-test/aks-neo4j-one:80"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-test
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: controller
        args:
          - /nginx-ingress-controller
          - --tcp-services-configmap=ingress-test/tcp-services
```

Did try it with and without config map as well as neo4j requires 7687 bolt port

Changing the services port to 7474, and browsing the External IP leads to a popup of username and password, and doesn't proceed for any inputs.

Comment: Once redirect /neo4jone to port 7474 (HTTP) of your Neo4j service and give it a try. I know Bolt doesn't use HTTP/HTTPS. Your ConfigMap tcp-services seems intended for that but ensure that your Nginx Ingress controller is configured to handle TCP traffic and that the tcp-services your ConfigMap is correctly set up. You may need to verify the Helm chart installation or controller configuration to enable TCP routing.

Comment: Yes tried with 7474 redirecting. Neo4j says Graph is Unreachable, and when I try to open the Url <ExternalIP>/neo4jone, it asks for a username password, and doesnt accept anything.
On the tcp-config, please check the edit. Added that as an argument in deployement for ingress according to https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/
Still the same issue persists.

Comment: check this document from neo4j  https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/kubernetes/multi-dc-cluster/aks/ and https://medium.com/globant/deploy-neo4j-on-kubernetes-using-helm-chart-and-azure-devops-615f3190ea96 and https://neo4j.com/developer-blog/deploying-neo4j-on-kubernetes-with-helm-charts/

Comment: Is there any change in this configuration needed with respect to the requirement. Went through the given material, unable to proceed

Answer (score 0):

To configure two separate Neo4j instances in an AKS cluster and direct traffic to them using Nginx Ingress based on URL paths, follow these instructions:

##### **Step 1: Install Nginx Ingress Controller**

Firstly, add the Helm repository for Nginx Ingress and install it:

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --create-namespace --namespace ingress-nginx
```

[image]

##### **Step 2: Deploy Neo4j Instances**

Create Kubernetes deployment files for each Neo4j instance.  For the first database (`db-1`):

```yaml
#File: db1-deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: neo4j-db1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: neo4j-db1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: neo4j-db1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: neo4j
          image: neo4j:latest
          env:
            - name: NEO4J_AUTH
              value: "neo4j/your_password_here"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7474
              name: http
            - containerPort: 7687
              name: bolt
```

For the second database (`db-2`):

```yaml
#File: db2-deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: neo4j-db2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: neo4j-db2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: neo4j-db2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: neo4j
          image: neo4j:latest
          env:
            - name: NEO4J_AUTH
              value: "neo4j/your_password_here"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7474
              name: http
            - containerPort: 7687
              name: bolt
```

Deploy these configurations using:

```bash
kubectl apply -f db1-deployment.yaml 
kubectl apply -f db2-deployment.yaml
```

[image]

##### **Step 3: Expose Neo4j Services**

Now, define services for each Neo4j deployment.
For `db-1`:

```yaml
# db1-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: neo4j-db1-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7474
      targetPort: 7474
    - name: bolt
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7687
      targetPort: 7687
  selector:
    app: neo4j-db1
```

For `db-2`:

```yaml
# db2-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: neo4j-db2-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7474
      targetPort: 7474
    - name: bolt
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7687
      targetPort: 7687
  selector:
    app: neo4j-db1
```

apply them:

```bash
kubectl apply -f db1-service.yaml
kubectl apply -f db2-service.yaml
```

[image]

##### **Step 4: Configure Ingress for Routing**

Set up an Ingress resource to route the external requests:

```yaml
# File: neo4j-ingress.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: neo4j-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /db1
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: neo4j-db1-service
                port:
                  number: 7474
          - path: /db2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: neo4j-db2-service
                port:
                  number: 7474
```

apply it using `kubectl apply -f neo4j-ingress.yaml`

[image]

Once you've applied the above configurations, create a ConfigMap for TCP routing:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-tcp
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  "7687": "default/neo4j-db1-service:7687"
```

Apply the ConfigMap:
`kubectl apply -f tcp-routing-configmap.yaml`
[image]

Then, update the Nginx Ingress Controller deployment to use this ConfigMap for TCP services:
`kubectl edit deployment ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx`

Add the `--tcp-services-configmap=default/nginx-ingress-tcp` argument under `spec.template.spec.containers[0].args`.

[image]

After applying the above configurations, you should be able to access your Neo4j instances at `http://<external-ip>/db1` for HTTP and `<external-ip>:7687` for Bolt. Find the external IP of your Nginx ingress controller with:

```
kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I can get the database instance started in the pod logs, everything else  configured as mentioned, still cannot connect to a specific database using ```<external_ip_address>/db1```
Facing the same "Service Unreachable" error.

Comment: Check if there are firewall rules or security groups that might be blocking access to the Ingress Controller.

Comment: Can you please let me know which settings should I check?